# Is it 'John and Mary's party' or 'John's and Mary's party'?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

Which is proper? I have looked for an answer but have not located any info for this question. I always thought John and Mary's was correct but a friend disagrees. Is it John's and Mary's party? Or John and Mary's party?

Answer (score 3):

*John and Mary's party* is referring to a party organized from both of them. *John's and Mary's parties* is referring to two different parties: one organized from John, and one from Mary.

Both are correct. Which one you use depends from the context.

Comment: If there were one party that John organized, and one that Mary did, surely *party* would have to become plural, right?  *"John's and Mary's parties were both fun"* sounds okay to me, but it doesn't sound right if *party* is singular.

Comment: You are correct; I was more focused on the partitive genitive than the usage of the plural.