# Question about genitive case

Tags: possessives

How should I put the genitive case in this sentence:

> - The investors’ and businessmen’s trust.

Or

> - The investors and businessmen’s trust.

I know if two nouns are sharing something we use one “S”, but I’m not sure if this applies to two plurals the first one end with s and the second doesn’t ?

I don’t want to use this form “ the trust of investors and businessmen” because my full sentence already has lots of “of”.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/105983/

Answer (score 1):

For non-count things separately possessed - use apostrophes for each possessor: Mary's and Bill's money (Mary's money and Bill's money). For non-countables shared or held in common, use an apostrophe for the last possessor only: Mary and Bill's money (the money which Mary and Bill own jointly). The investors and businessmen's trust.

> Sometimes possession is shared by several nouns. In these cases, just
>   make the last word in the series possessive.
>
> America and Canada's timber resources are dwindling
>
> Thomas and French's discovery shocked the world.
>
> Leslie and Eric's lasagna is to die for.
>
> These sentences all contain nouns that show joint ownership. In the
>   first sentence, the resources belong to America and Canada. In the
>   second sentence, the discovery belongs to both Thomas and French. In
>   the third sentence, the lasagna belongs to both Eric and Leslie.
>
> To show individual ownership, apply the possessive sign to each item
>   in the series.
>
> America's and Canada's timber resources are dwindling
>
> Thomas's and French's discoveries shocked the world. [Note: I
>   personally would have used Thomas' instead of Thomas's.]
>
> Leslie's and Eric's lasagnas are to die for.
>
> In these examples, each noun has individual ownership of resources, of
>   a discovery, or of a lasagna. These things are not shared.

"Possessive Case" in The Grammar Bible, Michael Strumpf, Macmillan (1999) page 29